# Path in the Destination folder is appending to the old path instead of showing the new path using NSIS

Tags: nsis

When I am installing, in the Destination Folder by default it is showing the path “C:\Program Files (x86)\DllTesting\” (It is as expected).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR0lr.png)

Then I tried to change the path to “C:\Program Files\AppTest”

But from the Browse once I selected the above path and clicked on “OK”, it is showing
“C:\Program Files\AppTest\DllTesting” instead of “C:\Program Files\AppTest”

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1M5p.png)
When I remove “DllTesting” from the below path then it is showing the new path correctly without appending to the old path.

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\DllTesting

But I can’t remove “DllTesting” from the above path, because by default I should display the path
“C:\Program Files (x86)\DllTesting\”

**Below is my code snippet:**

```
; DllTesting.nsi
;
;--------------------------------
!include LogicLib.nsh

Name "DllTesting"
OutFile "DllTesting.exe"

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\DllTesting

InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\NSIS_DllTesting" "Install_Dir"

RequestExecutionLevel admin

; Pages

Page components
Page directory
Page instfiles

UninstPage uninstConfirm
UninstPage instfiles

;--------------------------------

; The stuff to install
Section "DllTesting (required)"

  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  
  ; Write the installation path into the registry
  WriteRegStr HKLM SOFTWARE\NSIS_DllTesting "Install_Dir" "$INSTDIR"

  ; Write the uninstall keys for Windows
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DllTesting" "DisplayName" "NSIS DllTesting"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DllTesting" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"'
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DllTesting" "NoModify" 1
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DllTesting" "NoRepair" 1
  WriteUninstaller "uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd
```

Please help me how to change the path from browse without appending to the previous path?

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about InstallDir in documentation and you will find:

> Note that the part of this string following the last \ will be used if the user selects 'browse', and **may be appended back** on to the string at install time (**to disable this, end the directory with a `\`** (which will require the entire parameter to be enclosed with quotes).

Try changing

```
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\DllTesting
```

to

```
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\DllTesting\"
```